# Remove duplicate UserIDs (field) from QueryContainer

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am having some trouble with a certain query in elastic search C#.

I have this QueryContainer, with an inner QueryDescriptor and alot of inner QueryContainers \ QueryDescriptors,

but one main QueryContainer => `this._QueryContainer` that contains all the data.

the thing is, that the field UserID is not unique in `this._QueryContainer`, so when i return 20 unique users, first time all is ok, but next 20 users (for next page) i wouldn't know where to start `this.From`...

because the `this._QueryContainer` has duplicates but return unique because of aggregation. so there is a conflict.

Is there a way to make the query distinct from the start?

```
results = Client.Search<Users>(s => s
                .From(this.From)
                .Query(this._QueryContainer)
                .Aggregations(a => a
                    .Terms("unique", te => te
                        .Field(p => p.UserID)
                    )
                )
                .Size(20)
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.From()` and `.Size()` within your query do not affect the `Terms` aggregation that you have, they apply only to the `.Query()` part and the hits returned from this.

If you need to return lots of values from a Terms aggregation, which is what I think you'd like to do, you can

1.[Use partitioning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) to filter values, returning a large number of terms in multiple requests e.g.

```
var response = client.Search<Users>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("unique", st => st
            .Field(p => p.UserID)
            .Include(partition: 0, numberOfPartitions: 10)
            .Size(10000)
        )
    )
);

// get the next partition
response = client.Search<Users>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("unique", st => st
            .Field(p => p.UserID)
            .Include(partition: 1, numberOfPartitions: 10)
            .Size(10000)
        )
    )
);
```

2.[Use a Composite Aggregation with a Terms value source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_terms)

```
var response = client.Search<Users>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Composite("composite", c => c
            .Sources(so => so
                .Terms("unique", st => st
                    .Field(p => p.UserID)                   
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

// the following would be in a loop, to get all terms
var lastBucket = response.Aggregations.Composite("composite").Buckets.LastOrDefault();

if (lastBucket != null)
{
    // get next set of terms
    response = client.Search<Users>(s => s
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Composite("composite", c => c
                .Sources(so => so
                    .Terms("unique", st => st
                        .Field(p => p.UserID)
                    )
                )
                .After(lastBucket.Key)
            )
        )
    );
}
```